# JMeter execution on Unix based AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, unix, jmeter

We have an AWS Unix server where we have to do performance tests.

So is it possible to run jmeter on Unix aws servers ?

If it possible, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

JMeter is based on Java, as a consequence it works on any OS that supports Java.

And Unix is one of those, so you can use it without any problem on :

- Windows
- MacOSX
- Linux
- Unix

We frequently use in on AWS without problem.

Comment: thanks for that can you please explain how to set heap on aws server and how to execute it on servers with details. thanks in advance

Comment: On stackoverflow, once you get a valid answer, you need to accept it and upvote if you can. Then you ask another question that must not be too general , in the example below : 1 question for heap (but check before if nobody asked ), 1 about how to execute but this one is too wide

Answer (score 0):

Just like on Windows, just use `jmeter.sh` instead of `jmeter.bat`. JMeter works wherever Java works so

1. Make sure you have installed [Java 8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/java8-2100321.html) or later which is a pre-requisite for the latest (as of now) [JMeter 4.0](https://www.google.fr/search?q=blazemeter%20jmeter%204.0&oq=blazemeter%20jmeter%204.0&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i59l3.3140j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Refer your Unix distribution documentation with regards to how to install Java
2. Install JMeter (just [download](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) it and unpack somewhere)
3. Create a JMeter script (you can do this on any operating system) using JMeter GUI
4. Copy the script and all the dependencies (CSV files, files used for uploads, etc.) to the Unix server
5. Run JMeter normally in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   ./jmeter.sh -n -t /path/to/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl
   ```